# mixture of exponential and gamma distribution

Tags: distributions, monte-carlo, gamma-distribution, mixture-distribution

I'm not particularly good at statistics and whatever elementary statistics I have had exposure to are now rusty. However, I am working on a problem that I am hoping to gain some insights into:

My goal is to
1.find the expected value and the one standard deviation for the pdf associated with the empirical histogram
2.construct a pdf and sample from the pdf that best describes the histogram.

[image]

The empirical histogram depicts account balances of a population over a 12 months period. The smallest bin starts at 1.6 as I am only interested in

1. amount equal to or greater than this
2. if the smallest bin begins at 0.0, I have what looks like a zero - padded distribution that I do not wish to deal with.

I fitted various distributions to the empirical histogram to find that the gamma distribution of alpha param = 4.0 to work best.
As can be seen, the gamma distribution doesn't fit completely but it appears to be the best distribution amongst a reasonable number of distributions I have tried.

Is this the best approach?

Assume it is, in the bin interval between 1.6 and 3.0, is it possible to fit another distribution to this empirical histogram such that the empirical histogram is a mixture of, say an exponential (or something that is like an exponential or power law?) and a gamma distribution?

Any directions would be extremely helpful.

Comment: How many data points do you have? Is there a particular reason why you want to fit a distribution (and not determine the mean and SD, and resample, directly from your observations)?

Comment: The histogram itself represents the "pdf that best describes the histogram."

Comment: @StephanKolassa

The number of observations seen in empirical histogram is 900.

That is what I am trying to do but through first fitting the pdf that nicely fits the histogram before exploiting the formula associated with the mean and std of the associated pdf.

Would it not be risky to resample (with replacement, of course) and compute the mean and std without knowing exactly what pdf the histogram best represents?

Comment: You can *never* know "exactly what pdf the histogram represents."  It sounds like you are trying to estimate one.  That is the subject of statistical inference.  To accomplish it you need to (1) specify the set of possible pdfs and (2) indicate how you will measure the (inevitable) discrepancy between the data and the estimated pdf.  We need that information to come from you.

Comment: It may well be as risky - or more so - to try to fit a PDF to your data. If and only if the PDF fits your data well, then your samples from the PDF will look very similar to resamples from your observations. Which raises the question: if you will only get meaningfully different resamples from the two approaches if your PDF does not fit your data well, wouldn't that reduce your trust in your PDF?

Comment: If you assume a mixture model$$\omega \mathcal E(\lambda) + (1-\omega) \mathcal G(4,\alpha)$$as generating your data, running MLE will provide the most likely fit given that family of distributions.